# How to open a accordion item and fire its shown event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have an event handler for the `show.bs.collapse`-Event of a bootstrap accordion.

```
$('.collapse[data-location]').on('show.bs.collapse', function (e) {
  //Do Something...
}
```

This event handler is executed, if the user opens it. So far ok.

Now I want to open a specific item via Jquery:

```
$('.panel-collapse').collapse('show');
```

The specific item is opening, but the above event handler is not fired.

So how can I open a accordion item, with respecting every `show.bs.collapse`-Event handler?

This is my HTML, if this does matter:

```
<div class="panel-group accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-bordered panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#location1">Hamburg</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="location1" data-location="1" style="position:relative">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div>
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#TabTimespan1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Zeitraum</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation"><a href="#TabCompare1" role="tab" class="compare-tab-link" data-toggle="tab">Vergleich</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="TabTimespan1"></div>
                        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="TabCompare1"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- .... -->
</div>
```

Comment: Haven't figured out why, but it seems that your event is not attached to the set of element with the selector you're using. Try using the same selector for both js-methods; [example](https://jsfiddle.net/vmgkvccu/)

Comment: @empiric you should post this as answer. I will accept. thank you!